# What are the rewards of observing nafl fasts?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, nafl

Is there any special reward for observing nafl fasts?

Please, add reference from the Quran and Sunnah.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know nafl fasts is not mentioned in Qur'an directly but [this ayah](http://quran.com/2/183) is general on fast:

"O you who have believed, decreed upon you is fasting as it was decreed upon those before you that you may become righteous -"

You can look hadith references in this article: [VOLUNTARY FASTS](http://islam.ru/en/content/story/voluntary-fasts)